# Unable to get download option for excel export in Asp.net Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to download GridView content as excel by below code in asp.net webforms , the code is running properly but neither excel file is getting generated nor it shows popup to download:

```
private void ExportGridToExcel()
    {
        LoginView lw = (LoginView)Master.FindControl("LoginView1");
        ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)lw.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
        GridView gv = (GridView)cph.FindControl("GridView1");
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename = \""+ Guid.NewGuid() +".xls\"");
        Response.ContentType = "File/Data.xls";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
        new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        gv.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

While investigating in console, I get this:

```
Uncaught Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.
    at Function.Error$create [as create] (ScriptResource.axd:237)
    at Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_createPageRequestManagerParserError [as _createPageRequestManagerParserError] (ScriptResource.axd:665)
    at Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_parseDelta [as _parseDelta] (ScriptResource.axd:1435)
    at Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmitCompleted [as _onFormSubmitCompleted] (ScriptResource.axd:1314)
    at Array.<anonymous> (ScriptResource.axd:47)
    at ScriptResource.axd:3484
    at Sys$Net$WebRequest$completed [as completed] (ScriptResource.axd:6376)
    at XMLHttpRequest.Sys$Net$XMLHttpExecutor._onReadyStateChange (ScriptResource.axd:5996)
```

Comment: First, start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension. Then for a file download you need to trigger a full postback.

Comment: got it, the problem is relevant of postback, so I need to remove updatepanel?

Comment: Either that or assign a PostBack Trigger to the download button.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.